# jquery - using the .change even on a select drop down list to filter results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my code is:

```
$('select').change(function(){
 $('.sep14, .oct14').hide();
  var userChoice = "'." + $('select').val() + "'";
  $(userChoice).show();
});
```

So, when the user changes the dropdown list the two divs with those classes hide and then the variable stores the userChoice as something jquery can recognise which is then shown again, using .show().

For some reason though, this doesn't seem to work, anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `'` on `var userChoice = "'." + $('select').val() + "'";`

Code :

```
$('select').change(function() {
   $('.sep14, .oct14').hide();
   var userChoice = "." + $('select').val();
   $(userChoice).show();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/60hdwmbz/)

Also, this is somewhat weird way to achieve what you are doing, consider using `data-` attributes instead where you can create custom attributes with values, which are completely valid as of HTML5 like :-

```
$('select').change(function(){
   $('[data-toggler]').hide();
   $('[data-toggler=' + $(this).val() + ']').show();
});
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/60hdwmbz/1/)